# c# image recognition - RUN ON ENTIRE FOLDER

Tags: c#, image, hashcode

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace ConsoleApp1
   {
  class Program
{


    static String filename1;

    static String filename2;
    static int equalElements;

    //parse image file names into txt file for working cameras
    static StreamWriter writetext =  new StreamWriter(@"c: \Users\ChawlaRa\Desktop\FilezilleIMGS\MTO_Image\working.txt",true);

    static StreamWriter writetext2 = new StreamWriter(@"c: \Users\ChawlaRa\Desktop\FilezilleIMGS\MTO_Image\notworking.txt", true);

    //method which converts image to 16*16 gets hash code
    public static List<bool> GetHash(Bitmap bmpSource)
    {
        List<bool> lResult = new List<bool>();
        //create new image with 16x16 pixel
        Bitmap bmpMin = new Bitmap(bmpSource, new Size(16, 16));
        for (int j = 0; j < bmpMin.Height; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bmpMin.Width; i++)
            {
                //reduce colors to true / false                
                lResult.Add(bmpMin.GetPixel(i, j).GetBrightness() < 0.5f);
            }
        }
        return lResult;
    }


    public static int CompareImgSimilarityvalue(String filename1,String filename2)
    {
       List<bool> iHash1 = GetHash(new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\ChawlaRa\Desktop\FilezilleIMGS\MTO_Image\"+filename1+".jpg"));
        List <bool> iHash2 = GetHash(new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\ChawlaRa\Desktop\FilezilleIMGS\MTO_Image\" + filename2+".jpg"));

        //determine the number of equal pixel (x of 256) 256 is a perfect match
        equalElements = iHash1.Zip(iHash2, (i, j) => i == j).Count(eq => eq);

        return equalElements;
    }



    public static void Analyis()
        {

            filename1= Console.ReadLine();
            filename2= Console.ReadLine();

            CompareImgSimilarityvalue(filename1, filename2);


        //if LESS THAN 98% similar
        if (equalElements < 253.44)
        {
            //images different
            Console.WriteLine("NOT Same Images");

            Console.WriteLine("These images below are DIFFERENT - conclusion CAMERA WORKING");
            Console.WriteLine(filename1 + ".jpg");
            Console.WriteLine(filename2 + ".jpg");
            using ( writetext)
            {
                writetext.Write(filename1 + ".jpg");
                writetext.Write(",");
                writetext.Write(filename2 + ".jpg");
                writetext.Write(",");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The image file names of the non working cameras above have been appened to list of nonworking cameras.");
        }

        else
        //images same
        {
            Console.WriteLine("These images below are the same- conclusion CAMERA NOT WORKING ");
            Console.WriteLine(filename1 + ".jpg");
            Console.WriteLine(filename2 + ".jpg");

            using (writetext2)
            {
                writetext2.Write(filename1 + ".jpg");
                writetext2.Write(",");
                writetext2.Write(filename2 + ".jpg");
                writetext2.Write(",");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The image file names of the non working cameras above have been appened to list of nonworking cameras.");

        }
           // Console.WriteLine(equalElements);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }



    //main test harness

    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        Analyis();





    }
}
   }
```

So here is my CODE for an application which asks the user for 2 image files which compares them and if its the same, it'll append the name of the 2 files to a text file nonworking and if it's different it'll append the name of the 2 img files to a text file called WORKING.

Basically my problem is USER INPUT. The directory which contains the images contains around 1100 images, the first image compares to the 2nd, the 3rd to the 4th and so on,

So i dont want to manually type each image file name to compare it to the second file, I want to loop through the entire MTOImage directory and compare images while appending the names of the similar/different cameras to their respective txt files.

I'm having a hard time automating this can anyone help? Thank-you

UPDATE: Edited Analysis Method Arman Suggestion

```
 public static void Analyis()
        {
        /*
            filename1= Console.ReadLine();
            filename2= Console.ReadLine();

            CompareImgSimilarityvalue(filename1, filename2);
        */




        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\ChawlaRa\Desktop\FilezilleIMGS\MTO_Image");
        for (var i = 0; i < (files.Length - 1); i++)
        {
            CompareImgSimilarityvalue(files[i], files[i + 1]);





            //if LESS THAN 98% similar
            if (equalElements < 253.44)
            {
                //images different camera working
                Console.WriteLine("NOT Same Images");

                Console.WriteLine("These images below are DIFFERENT - conclusion CAMERA WORKING");
                Console.WriteLine(files[i] + ".jpg");
                Console.WriteLine(files[i+1] + ".jpg");
                using (writetext)
                {
                    writetext.Write(files[i] + ".jpg");
                    writetext.Write(",");
                    writetext.Write(files[i+1] + ".jpg");
                    writetext.Write(",");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("The image file names of the  working cameras above have been appened to list of working cameras.");
            }

            else
            //images same camera frozen
            {
                Console.WriteLine("These images below are the same- conclusion CAMERA NOT WORKING ");
                Console.WriteLine(files[i] + ".jpg");
                Console.WriteLine(files[i+1] + ".jpg");

                using (writetext2)
                {
                    writetext2.Write(files[i] + ".jpg");
                    writetext2.Write(",");
                    writetext2.Write(files[i+1] + ".jpg");
                    writetext2.Write(",");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("The image file names of the non working cameras above have been appened to list of nonworking cameras.");

            }
        }
           // Console.WriteLine(equalElements);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
```

Comment: So you have `CompareImgSimilarityvalue(filename1, filename2);`, and you want to loop through your directory to compare the 1st file to the 2nd, the 3rd to the 4th, and so on? Is that correct? How are these files ordered?

Comment: Yes, I gave it two parameters because I just wanted to get it working if I manually enter both the files names.

Comment: The ordering of the image files is as such first image name CR01-1-20170623-1308, second image name CR01-1-20170623-1327, these two need to be compared because they are the first TWO files in the image folder. Essentially I want the 1st file to be compared to the 2nd , the 3rd to the 4th, the 5th to the 6th and so on- It should be compared with the next image in the folder.

Comment: How do I do that^?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Analyis();
        }

        //method which converts image to 16*16 gets hash code
        public static List<bool> GetHash(Bitmap bmpSource)
        {
            List<bool> lResult = new List<bool>();
            //create new image with 16x16 pixel
            Bitmap bmpMin = new Bitmap(bmpSource, new Size(16, 16));
            for (int j = 0; j < bmpMin.Height; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < bmpMin.Width; i++)
                {
                    //reduce colors to true / false                
                    lResult.Add(bmpMin.GetPixel(i, j).GetBrightness() < 0.5f);
                }
            }
            return lResult;
        }


        public static int CompareImgSimilarityvalue(String filename1, String filename2)
        {
            List<bool> iHash1 = GetHash(new Bitmap(filename1));
            List<bool> iHash2 = GetHash(new Bitmap(filename2));

            //determine the number of equal pixel (x of 256) 256 is a perfect match
            int equalElements = iHash1.Zip(iHash2, (i, j) => i == j).Count(eq => eq);

            return equalElements;
        }



        public static void Analyis()
        {
            var writetext = new StreamWriter(@"C:\stackoverflowtests\4476837\working.txt", true);
            var writetext2 = new StreamWriter(@"C:\stackoverflowtests\4476837\notworking.txt", true);

            try
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\stackoverflowtests\4476837\MTO_Image");
                for (var i = 0; i < (files.Length - 1); i++)
                {
                    string filename1 = files[i];
                    string filename2 = files[i + 1];
                    int equalElements = CompareImgSimilarityvalue(filename1, filename2);

                    //if LESS THAN 98% similar
                    if (equalElements < 253.44)
                    {
                        //images different
                        Console.WriteLine("NOT Same Images");

                        Console.WriteLine("These images below are DIFFERENT - conclusion CAMERA WORKING");
                        Console.WriteLine(filename1);
                        Console.WriteLine(filename2);

                        // Write to files
                        writetext.Write(filename1);
                        writetext.Write(",");
                        writetext.Write(filename2);
                        writetext.Write(",");

                        Console.WriteLine("The image file names of the non working cameras above have been appened to list of nonworking cameras.");
                    }

                    else
                    //images same
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("These images below are the same- conclusion CAMERA NOT WORKING ");
                        Console.WriteLine(filename1);
                        Console.WriteLine(filename2);

                        // Write to files
                        writetext2.Write(filename1);
                        writetext2.Write(",");
                        writetext2.Write(filename2);
                        writetext2.Write(",");

                        Console.WriteLine("The image file names of the non working cameras above have been appened to list of nonworking cameras.");

                    }
                    // Console.WriteLine(equalElements);                    
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                // Catch exceptions here
            }
            finally
            {
                writetext.Dispose();
                writetext2.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you suggest I replace this snippet of code with in my code?

Comment: If i'm understanding your question correctly, in your Analysis() method you can get rid of the Console.Readline(); statements and replace it with the code I've posted.

Comment: Scratch that - you can pretty much surround your entire code with it. Basically anywhere you have filename1 + ".jpg" and filename2 + ".jpg", you can replace it with files[i] and files[i+1], respectively.

Comment: I'm getting an error System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'  in my compareImgSimilarity method at line " List<bool> iHash1 = GetHash(new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\ChawlaRa\Desktop\FilezilleIMGS\MTO_Image\"+filename1+".jpg"));"

Comment: I have edited and added my newly formatted Analysis method

Comment: I updated the code. Try that.
Sorry, formatting error. I pasted the whole thing.

Comment: Arman, It works But it only adds the image file names of the first two images compared to the txt file, nothing after?

Comment: this is the working text file output: C:\Users\ChawlaRa\Desktop\FilezilleIMGS\MTO_Image\CR01-1-20170623-1308.jpg,C:\Users\ChawlaRa\Desktop\FilezilleIMGS\MTO_Image\CR01-1-20170623-1327.jpg,

Comment: Sorry probably related to the streamwriter? I have updated the code again and tested it using 5 jpgs on my system. It appears to be working for me. Make sure you change the paths back to what you had!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overusing static methods and variables. E.g. I'd make `equalElements` a local variable, so you can use it to loop through all your files easier:

```
public int CompareImgSimilarityvalue(String filename1, String filename2)
    {
        List<bool> iHash1 = GetHash(new Bitmap(filename1));
        List<bool> iHash2 = GetHash(new Bitmap(filename2));

        //determine the number of equal pixel (x of 256) 256 is a perfect match
        return iHash1.Zip(iHash2, (i, j) => i == j).Count(eq => eq);

    }

    public static void Analyis()
    {

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\ChawlaRa\Desktop\FilezilleIMGS\MTO_Image\", "*.jpg");

        Array.Sort(files);

        int equalElements = 0;
        StringBuilder workingText = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder notWorkingText = new StringBuilder();


        for (var i = 0; i < (files.Length - 1); i++)
        {
            equalElements = CompareImgSimilarityvalue(files[i], files[i + 1]);



            //if LESS THAN 98% similar
            if (equalElements < 253.44)
            {
                //images different
                Console.WriteLine("NOT Same Images");

                Console.WriteLine("These images below are DIFFERENT - conclusion CAMERA WORKING");
                Console.WriteLine(files[i] + ".jpg");
                Console.WriteLine(files[i+1] + ".jpg");

                workingText.AppendLine(files[i] + ".jpg");
                workingText.AppendLine(",");
                workingText.AppendLine(files[i+1] + ".jpg");
                workingText.AppendLine(",");

                Console.WriteLine("The image file names of the non working cameras above have been appended to list of nonworking cameras.");
            }

            else
            //images same
            {
                Console.WriteLine("These images below are the same- conclusion CAMERA NOT WORKING ");
                Console.WriteLine(files[i] + ".jpg");
                Console.WriteLine(files[i+1] + ".jpg");


                notWorkingText.AppendLine(files[i] + ".jpg");
                notWorkingText.AppendLine(",");
                notWorkingText.AppendLine(files[i+1] + ".jpg");
                notWorkingText.AppendLine(",");

                Console.WriteLine("The image file names of the non working cameras above have been appended to list of nonworking cameras.");

            }

        }
        // Console.WriteLine(equalElements);


        // you probably shouldn't be using static StreamWriters here 
        using (writetext) 
        {
            writetext.Write(workingText.ToString());
        }    
        using (writetext2) 
        {
            writetext2.Write(notWorkingText.ToString());
        }          

        Console.ReadLine();


    }
```

Comment: ystem.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.'

Comment: Ahh, you can replace the StreamWriter objects there with a StringBuilder, and then write the appended StringBuilder text to a file all at once.

Comment: Although you really shouldn't be using static everything everywhere. You can create the `StreamWriter`s in the `Analysis()` method since that's the only place you use them. No point in declaring them static.